# How do I create and array of pointers to functions?

Tags: c++, c++11

gcc 6.4.0
win 7
Netbeans 8.2

I can't figure what I'm doing wrong.

```
#ifndef TYPEDEF_H
#define TYPEDEF_H

class Typedef {
   class Alphabet { };
   class Tuple { };
   class Operations { };
public:
   void test();
private:
   Tuple constant(long one, long two, Alphabet& bet, Operations& op) { return Tuple(); } ;
   Tuple expression(long one, long two, Alphabet& bet, Operations& op) {return Tuple(); } ;
};

#endif /* TYPEDEF_H */

===================== .cpp file ========================
#include "Typedef.h"

void Typedef::test() {
   typedef Tuple (*fn)(long, long, Alphabet&, Operations&);
   fn func[]      = { constant, expression };
   Tuple (*fnc[2])= { constant, expression };
}
```

> Typedef.cpp: In member function 'void Typedef::test()':
>
> Typedef.cpp:6:44: error: cannot convert 'Typedef::constant' from type
>   'Typedef::Tuple (Typedef::)(long int, long int, Typedef::Alphabet&,
>   Typedef::Operations&)' to type 'fn {aka Typedef::Tuple (*)(long int,
>   long int, Typedef::Alphabet&, Typedef::Operations&)}'
>       fn func[]      = { constant, expression };

The error message is repeated for all four instances. I've tried &constant and as expected it didn't work.

Comment: Member functions aren't functions...

Comment: You may be interested in [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Answer (score 2):

A class member function is special in that it accepts an additional invisible argument, the `this*` pointer. Also, a member function and a free function are completely different types, even if the latter had the extra argument compatible with the `this*` type.

To capture a pointer to the member function, use the member pointer syntax (`Typedef::*`), like this:

```
void Typedef::test() {
  typedef Tuple (Typedef::*fn)(long, long, Alphabet&, Operations&);
  fn func[] = { &Typedef::constant, &Typedef::expression };
}
```

In addition, an address of a member function can be taken only on fully-qualified names (reference: [[expr.unary.op]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#4)), so you have to use `&Typedef::constant, &Typedef::expression`.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why the Typdef:: is required since the functions are visible.

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez see my updates. Typedef::* here is not for visibility but a member pointer syntax.